# Spark Dataset encoder for heterogeneous lists (not tuples)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'd like to use a Spark Dataset to store a collection of data points where each row is a heterogeneous list combining primitive types and case classes.  For example, one row might be

```scala
val row = List[Any](1, 2.0, 3L, CaseClass1(4, 5, 6), CaseClass2(7, 8))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make an Encoder for the entire List[Any]. 
 At runtime, I will have an Encoder and a TypeTag for each of the individual types, but unfortunately I won't know the exact length of the list at compile time (which I think prevents me from using a tuple to store each row).

Also, I've tried using a RowEncoder based on the schema of the data (which I can construct using the TypeTags and ScalaReflection.schemaFor).  However, that approach doesn't seem to handle case classes appearing inside each row.  (With the above example, it gives me an error saying that CaseClass1 (or CaseClass2) is not a supported data type.)

So, if I have rows of heterogenous lists with a corresponding Encoder and a TypeTag for each position in the list (available at runtime), but I don't know the length of the list at compile time, **how can I encode these rows as either a Dataset or DataFrame?**

I suspect that a solution will involve either (1) transforming the data to turn any nested case classes into nested sql.Row instances, or (2) explicitly constructing an Encoder or ExpressionEncoder based on the available Encoders and TypeTags.

Comment: Ad (2) Unfortunately if you implement custom encoder for `List[Any]` machinery in `ExpressionEncoder` and `ScalaReflection` won't be able to use it if you nest `List[Any]` in another type (eg. in case class). So if you want to nest `List[Any]` you'll have to reimplement `ExpressionEncoder` and `ScalaReflection`.

Comment: Do all rows have the same schema? (I suspect so if you wish to use the Dataset API) If so, maybe you could take the first row, use reflection to create a `List[Any] => Row` function, and broadcast it to convert your `RDD[List[Any]]` to a Dataset? Not sure if it works, just an idea.